# How to solve 'vector subscript out of range' error?

Tags: c++, neural-network, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to learn about neural networks using C++, and found a tutorial about digit recognition, but when I run the code I get an error that say "debug assertion failed, vector subscript out of range." Apparently the problem is in the `loadTraining` function, but don't know how to modify it to eliminate the error.

```
void loadTraining(const char *filename, vector<vector<double>> &input, vector<vector<double>> &output) 
{
    int trainingSize = 946;
    input.resize(trainingSize);
    output.resize(trainingSize);

    ifstream file(filename);
    if(file) 
    {
        string line;
        int n;
        for (int i=0 ; i<trainingSize ; i++) // load 946 examples
        {
            for (int h=0 ; h<32 ; h++) // 'images' are 32*32 pixels
            {
                getline(file, line);
                for (int w=0 ; w<32 ; w++)
                {
                    input[i].push_back(atoi(line.substr(w,1).c_str()));
                }
            }
            getline(file, line);
            output[i].resize(10); // output is a vector of size 10
            n = atoi(line.substr(0,1).c_str());
            output[i][n] = 1; // set index that represent the number to 1, other are automatically 0 because of the resize()
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

The file consist of 32*32 arrays of binary digits.
[This is one training exmple.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08T4o.png)

I'm using visual studio 2013.

Comment: `getline` and `atoi` can fail, are you sure that they do not fail?

Comment: You can break at the specific time where this occures, and use the debugger to find out the root cause. As is, this isn't fit for Stack Overflow. Since `i` looks okay, I suspect the `n` being problematic (i.e. greater or equal to ten, or negative).

Comment: `substr(...).c_str()` returns a dangling pointer to the dead temporary substring.

Comment: "The file consist of 32*32 arrays of binary digits" then why are you using a string to integer function when reading them? Do you instead mean "The file consist of 32 lines each of 32 digits"?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of one of these files?

Comment: @mch getline works fine, I think the atoi is the probem.

Comment: @Caleth I uploaded one of the training examples.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `std::stoi` instead of `atoi`. Enclose `std::stoi` in `try` and `catch` block to check conversion issue. Also check if `n >= 0 && n < 10` to address potential subscript errors.

Comment: When using `stoi` I get "exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion". When using `atoi` I get "exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string. n is equal to zero.

Comment: I would suggest that you check that data is properly read  first with `if getline(file, line)`. Also output line to see that the data read is what you are expecting.